# Chronic 404 errors on my Wordpress Blog and WooCommerce My Subscription Pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, subscription, chronic

I'm getting chronic 404 errors on my WooCommerce Subscription and blank page on my Wordpress Blog page.

This problem gets fixed when I visit Permalink Settings in Wordpress admin dashboard and I don't even have to hit save. But after a while the problem occurs again.

I've reset .htaccess and made it writeable, reset all the caches but it didn't help.